# Sharing files from my Macbook to Windows Desktop

Tags: windows, macos, file-sharing

What's the most dependable way to share files and folders on a OS X to Windows (I'm using 7). I've followed this guide: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1812

However, this method does not seem dependable (Works only some of the time). My Macbook does not always show up under the Network on Windows. On certain occasions, turning off windows file sharing completely (in OS X preferences), restarting my Macbook and turning it back on helps. Is there any reason why this is happening? Is there an alternative method?

Comment: email yourself? Networked hard drive?

Comment: I meant an alternative software solution (maybe I'm just doing something wrong). Some files are too large to email. I already have Dropbox setup for the smaller stuff.

Comment: You could checkout Dropbox (getdropbox.com)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I've had a lot of the problems you've mentioned, and so I've gone to having windows machines share a folder that remote users can modify.  I temporarily move stuff there in windows to share it, and I drop stuff in there from mac to copy it to windows.

Setup a shared folder in windows ([here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/) is a guide for windows 7, but most other versions are similar), be sure to click the checkbox to let remote users change your files, voila.

If you're using 10.5 or later, windows computers should show up in Finder, if they don't, just open a connection (Command+K in finder) and type: smb://computername/ and it will open a connection.  Either way, you should be good to go.